# How to turn on searchSubtree for LDAP on Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap

I have a Spring boot application with LDAP authentication.

I need to have javax.naming.directory.SearchControls with SUBTREE_SCOPE to be able to retrieve the user groups, but I can't find a way to turn that on.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter(ldap.getUserFilter())
        .userSearchBase(ldap.getUserBaseDN())
        .groupSearchFilter(ldap.getGroupFilter())
        .groupSearchBase(ldap.getGroupBaseDN())
        .groupRoleAttribute(ldap.getGroupNameAttribute())
        .contextSource()
            .url(ldap.getUrl())
            .managerDn(ldap.getManagerDn())
            .managerPassword(ldap.getManagerPassword());
}

public void setLdap(LdapProperties ldap) {
    this.ldap = ldap;
}
}
```